# if ( l <= A_heap_size && A.get(l).key < A.get(i).key ) // ERROR: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an error message "cannot find symbol" associated with this part of the condition:

```
    PQHeap.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
        if ( l <= A_heap_size && A.get(l).key < A.get(i).key ) 
                                         ^
  symbol:   variable key
  location: class Object
PQHeap.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
        if ( l <= A_heap_size && A.get(l).key < A.get(i).key ) 
                                                        ^
  symbol:   variable key
  location: class Object
PQHeap.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
        if ( r <= A_heap_size && A.get(r).key < A.get(smallest).key )
                                         ^
  symbol:   variable key
  location: class Object
PQHeap.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
        if ( r <= A_heap_size && A.get(r).key < A.get(smallest).key )
                                                               ^
  symbol:   variable key
  location: class Object
PQHeap.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
                Collections.swap( A, i, smallest );
                ^
  symbol:   variable Collections
  location: class PQHeap
PQHeap.java:42: error: constructor Element in class Element cannot be applied to given types;
        Element max = new Element();
                      ^
  required: int,Object
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
PQHeap.java:44: error: no suitable method found for set(int)
        A.set(1).key = A.get(A_heap_size).key;
         ^
    method List.set(int,Element) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method AbstractList.set(int,Element) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method ArrayList.set(int,Element) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
PQHeap.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
                Collections.swap(A, i, i/2);
                ^
  symbol:   variable Collections
  location: class PQHeap
8 errors
```

Below is extra info.
Encoding: UTF-8. 
ArrayLIst is imported (import java.util.ArrayList;) prior to class definition. 
A_heap_size defined outside method as private int. 
A defined outside method as public ArrayList . 
Element constructor has an instance variable int key. 
(Element class is a facit I got, so error is not from there. Element.java compiled flawlessly).

Thanks in advance

P.S.: when I remove .key I get another error but I'm not sure though whether above described problem stems from that

Comment: What are `l` and `i`? post all relevant code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: When we read your insufficient input we have no idea where your problem stems from. Sorry, but we are no wizards here.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. I'm not sure I would be able to provide more code though: I'm a student, so more code could mean risk of being accused of plagiarism when submitting assignment although I wrote the code. But I would happily provide more info. Otherwise I could remove the question. I'm open for suggestions. thanks in advance.

Comment: While we have no issues with you asking for homework help per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll look it up once more.

Comment: Start reading the various links that were provided to you, like [mcve]. You do not need to post ALL code. Just a snippet that **shows** the problem; and that is complete enough to compile/run on our end.

Comment: And also, always post the exact and complete error message. It tells **which** symbol can't be resolved, but you didn't post that. And please, choose meaningful names, with much more than one letter, for your variables, and respect the Java naming conventions: variables start with a lowercase letter and are camelCase.

Comment: l and i are indices/positions of Elements within ArrayList, thanks.

Comment: Variables are named so of respect to "algorithms+data structures" teacher who got to correct all source code for 100 studends besides attending to his other duties. The more variables resemble Cormen's pseudocode the faster it would be for the teacher to find the errors within my implementation of the algorithm.

Comment: PQHeap.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
            if ( l <= A_heap_size && A.get(l).key < A.get(i).key ) 
                                         ^
//(full error statement is too long by 1350 characters. Just tried to copypaste it). ^ points at dot in get(l).key

Comment: Post that, properly formatted, and looking **exactly** as it looks in your console, in the question itself. Whether your teacher chooses to use unreadable code is irrelevant to us. If you ask us for help, you should try making your code as readable as possible.

Comment: Ok, thanks. How do I do that? I'll correct it right away. Thanks

Comment: By clicking the edit link at the bottom of your question.

Comment: OK, thanks I,ll correct the question itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `A.get()`. That returns a `java.lang.Object`. You're trying to access the `key` attribute f this object. But there is no attribute `key` in the class `Object`. Hence the error.

You're probaly using raw types, i.e. using a `List` instead of a `List<MyClassWhichHasAKeyAttribute>`. Don't use raw types.

There are several other potential explanations, but since you won't post your code, this is the best guess we can make.

The other errors come from not importing a class, or from calling methods that don't exist. Read the javadoc.